# text-decoration doesn't work on a button element in Firefox, workaround?

Tags: css, firefox, button

I've got a simple button with a single css-style, like this:

```
<button style="text-decoration:underline">That's a button</button>
```

Firebug tells me in the computed styles tab that indeed text-decoration is set to underline. However the Button-text is not underlined, why not?
Obviously it's an issue with Firefox (3.6), since Chrome and IE both underline the button-text.
Is there some css-workaround for Firefox, or do I have to put the button in an outer div with the text-decoration style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little more research online has produced a more elegant workaround, and convinced me it probably is a 'bug'. It is almost a type of 'hasLayout' for FireFox (not really, but acts similar). If you add any of the following, it shows the underline: `position: absolute`, `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, `float: left` (or right). So:

```
<button style="text-decoration:underline; display: inline-block;">That's a button</button>
```

Comment: hasLayout... a word that leads to the dark side *shiver*.

anyway, works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a 'bug' (I don't actually know what the web standards say about the `button` element, so I hesitate to proclaim it a 'bug' or just a difference in browser interpretations). This worked, but is really not much different than your `div` wrapper solution:

```
<button ><span style="text-decoration:underline">That's a button</span></button>
```